# Wrong decimal output from verilog substraction

Tags: verilog

I am really new to verilog...I wrote a adder–subtractor in Verilog and the subtarct only works when A is greater than B, it will give me a wrong decimal output if the result is a negative number, see result from the test bench:

```
time= 0 A= 0 B= 0 : R= 0
time= 100 A= 1 B= 0 : R= 1
time= 110 A= 24512 B= 3 : R= 24509
time= 120 A= 262141 B= 10 : R= 262131
time= 130 A= 14 B= 81 : R=4294967229
time= 140 A= 15 B= 34 : R=4294967277
```

It seems to be that verilog doesn't know where the sign bit is and translate everything as a positive number, what should I do to get a correct output?

Comment: It's hard to know what might be wrong with your Verilog without being able to see it...

Comment: Show us your `$display` or similar statements. It looks like a clear case of signed vs. unsigned representation.

Answer (score 1):

You have most likely declared A, B and R as unsigned variables. If you declare them as signed, you will see the right result.

```
reg signed [31:0] A, B, R;
```

If you just want to see the result in a signed format, you can do

```
$display("time= %t A= %0d B= %0d : R= %0d",$time, A, B, $signed(R));
```